# Why does GitHub API rate limit decrease from 5000 to >30 after initial request?

Tags: ruby, github-api, octokit

I have a list of GH users that I am searching by email address. However, the api rate limit becomes really stingy after the initial request.

```rb
client = Octokit::Client.new(:access_token => TOKEN)

Users.find_each do |user|
  puts "Rate limit #{client.rate_limit.remaining}"

  client.search_users(user.email)
  
  #...

  # Pause a moment.
  sleep(1)
end
```

Initially, the rate limit is reported as 5000. However, it decreases dramatically after the first search:

```
Rate limit 5000
Rate limit 27
Rate limit 26
Rate limit 25
Rate limit 24
Rate limit 23
Rate limit 22
Rate limit 21
Rate limit 20
...
```

Is there any reason why the rate limit drops so sharply? Am I right in assuming the rate limit is stricter for these kind of searches?

Comment: PSA: It's 2024 and you can confidently write `access_token: TOKEN` as the Ruby 1.8 style is no longer a requirement.

Comment: Is there a rate limit "cost" for this kind of query?

Comment: Perhaps. "Some REST API endpoints have a different point cost that is not shared publicly." https://docs.github.com/en/rest/using-the-rest-api/rate-limits-for-the-rest-api?apiVersion=2022-11-28#calculating-points-for-the-secondary-rate-limit

Comment: You can [get the current rate limits](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/rate-limit/rate-limit?apiVersion=2022-11-28#get-rate-limit-status-for-the-authenticated-user) via `GET https://api.github.com/rate_limit`. The example response shows 5,000 for "core" and 30 for "search" which reflects the values you are seeing.

Comment: BTW, it might make more sense to use GitHub usernames instead of email addresses so you don't have to resort to the search in the first place.